# Ms access select data greater than datetime range

Tags: ms-access, datetime, ms-access-2007

How to select Data in ms access above this datetime range

like select * from logevents where logTime>='12/6/2012 3:54:15 PM'

logTime is Datetime field

Comment: What's wrong with the query you have?

Comment: Don't put it in quotes. Either leave the date as is or add # signs around it. It should just run fine as WHERE logTime >= 12/04/12 , It's not even picky about 12/4/12 opposed to 12/03/2012.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Adding # signs on each end of your date lets Access know that this is a date type.

```
select * from logevents where logTime>=#12/6/2012 3:54:15 PM#
```

Answer (score 0):

This depends on if your Access database is created/opened in ANSI 92 mode:
non-ANSI 92: 
Access uses # ... # around dates and uses * (multiple characters) and ? (one character) for wildcards when using LIKE. For example:

> SELECT * FROM logevents WHERE logTime>=#12/6/2012# AND description
>   like '*error*'

ANSI 92:
Access uses ' ... ' around dates and uses % and ? for wildscards when using LIKE. This mode looks more like how MySQL, Oracle and MSSQL work with dates and wildcards. For example:

> SELECT * FROM logevents WHERE logTime>='12/6/2012' AND description
>   like '%error%'

Be sure to check the date format settings. It can dd/mm/yyyy or dd-mm-yyyy or something else, this depends on your regional settings. Just inspect your table for a date column for example data.

To switch to ANSI-92 in Access 2007, but this should not be hard to apply to different versions:
-open MS Access
-click the Office button on top left
-click "Access Options" button
-select "Object Designers" from the left pane
-look for "Query Design" section, there is an option "SQL Server Compatible Syntac (ANSI 92).
-if you have an open database, you can check on "This Database" or check the "Default for new databases" for default setup on all new databases
-click "OK" button to accept the changes