# Combine two queries in one, SQL MS Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table with the following records:

```
date, name, amount, balance, debit_credit.
```

This table represents the sample with observations on several firms across some time period.

I'd like to make the following table with the following records:

```
aggregate1, aggregate2, aggregate3, aggregate4, name.
```

where:

```
aggregate1 - sum of amount for all names where balance equals 1500, 1501;
aggregate2 - sum of amount for all names where balance equals 1400, 1401;
aggregate3 - sum of amount for all names where balance equals 1300, 1301;
```

I have written the following SQL query to calculate the aggregate1.

```
SELECT Sum(Firms.amount)/100 AS [aggregate1], Firms.name
FROM Firms
where Firms.Balance in (1500, 1502)
GROUP BY Firms.name;
```

But, I am curiouse how to combine the outputs in one table (see above) of queries with different where conditions?
Moreover, I'd like to know, how to set the date as the parameter for this query?

I will appreciate your suggestions and solutions. Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
SELECT
    Firms.name,
    SUM(iif(Firms.Balance IN (1500, 1502),Firms.amount,0))/100 AS aggregate1,
    SUM(iif(Firms.Balance IN (1400, 1401),Firms.amount,0))/100 AS aggregate2,
    SUM(iif(Firms.Balance IN (1300, 1301),Firms.amount,0))/100 AS aggregate3
FROM Firms
WHERE Firms.date >= #12/6/2012 3:54:15 PM#  
GROUP BY Firms.name;
```

References:

- [MS Access: iif Function](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php)
- [Ms access select data greater than datetime range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769571/ms-access-select-data-greater-than-datetime-range)

Comment: Wow, that's worked. Thank you. Could you suggest how to insert date as the parameter in this query?